# XHR returning a string float for the ETag response header instead of actual response header

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, etag

I have the following code utilizing `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('PUT', url);

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    const eTag = xhr.getResponseHeader('ETag');
    console.log({ eTag, headers: xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() });
  }
});

xhr.send(chunk);
```

When I run this code and look at the response in the Firefox developer tools I see that the response has an `ETag` header of a long Base64 string:

[image: ETag]

However, when I look in the console, I see an `ETag` header that is nowhere near the same:

[image: console.log]

```
Object { eTag: "0.07594210872820828", headers: "content-length: 0\r\netag: 0.07594210872820828\r\n" }
```

Rather than the Base64 string I'm seeing in the devtools, I'm getting a float as a string that doesn't appear to have any relation to the Base64 string. There is only one header that looks anything like `ETag`:

[image: headers]

This is CloudFlare R2 for whatever that's worth. As you can see I have CORS configured so the service responds with `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag`.

What's going on that the JavaScript code appears to be getting a different value from what is shown in the developer tools?

Comment: At first glance, your code looks correct. I have a feeling this is a Cloudflare issue. I found something along that lines here: https://github.com/nextcloud/contacts/issues/1157

Comment: I don't see how it could be a cloudflare issue though, I see the `ETag` in the dev tools, the XHR code is just giving me a different value for some reason.

Comment: The same thing is happening for `fetch`, for whatever reason the `ETag` header is a float string.

Comment: There appears to be something strange going on with Firefox here. I ran my code in Chrome and I get the real `ETag` header there.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the data gets corrupted on Firefox. I'd try to disable the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was this extension: https://github.com/ClearURLs/Addon

It has an option that is enabled by default: `Filters ETag Headers From Requests.` Turning that option off fixed the issue.